# SFML - Rotating a sprite around its center using a Transform

Tags: rotation, sfml

I have an object that needs to be able to be rotated around its center, but keeping the same origin (for setting position, etc). So, I figured I needed to use a `Transform.`

Code is in Java (JSFML), but I figured the syntax was similar and able to be understood by anyone familiar with SFML.

```
public class DoorTile extends Tile {

    private Transform t;

    public DoorTile() {
        ...
        t = new Transform();
        ...
        sprite.setTexture(TileTextures.DOORTEXTURE);
    }

    public void rotateAroundCenter(float degrees) {
        Vector2f center = SpriteUtils.getTextureCenter(TileTextures.DOORTEXTURE);
        t = Transform.rotate(t, degrees, center.x, center.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(RenderTarget rt, RenderStates states) {
        RenderStates newStates = new RenderStates(Transform.combine(t, states.transform));
        sprite.draw(rt, newStates);
    }
```

`getTextureCenter(Texture t)` returns the center coordinates of `t`.

Now, when I apply this rotation, my sprites have a weird behavior. At first, using 45 degrees as a test, they completely disappeared from the screen. So then I tried 1 degree. The sprites affected seemed to have pieces "cut off" and translated downward. 
Here's a picture, using 1 degree as an argument:

[image: Sprites affected are the little white things.]

For context, I'm trying to rotate those white sprites (will be 'doors') so they fit properly in the corridor. E.g. horizontal on vertical cooridors, vertical on horizontal corridors. (The white part of the sprite is a placeholder for transparency, that's just there for debugging purposes.)

What should I do to be able to make this work properly? That is, how can I:

1. Rotate a sprite around its center
2. Keep the original origin (top left corner)

Comment: Every time you go to rotate an object around itself, make sure to undo its translation, IE its position. Wherever their position is at the time of rotating, is where they will rotate around when you apply a rotation. So, to rotate an object around its center origin you would have to move that object half of its width and height past the world coordinates 0,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was, that I wasn't accounting for the way Transform handles its transforms (that is, from (0, 0)). So, even if I tried rotating around the center of the texture (in this case a 16x16 texture), it would rotate all my sprites around (8, 8), which is why my results are odd. So, I changed my draw function to account for the position of the sprites:

```
public void rotateAroundCenter(float degrees) {
    ending.vector.Vector2f center = SpriteUtils.getTextureCenter(TileTextures.DOORTEXTURE);
    ending.vector.Vector2f rotateOrigin = new ending.vector.Vector2f(sprite.getPosition()).add(center);
    transform = Transform.rotate(transform, degrees, rotateOrigin.x, rotateOrigin.y);
}
```

Also, I needed to make sure I set the position of the sprites before rotation, as the draw() method would still think I was rotating them on (8, 8) otherwise (since the sprite's default position is (0, 0)).